Powershell Script for installing Qualys Agent
I need to install Qualys Agent Extension on Azure VMs.
Below scripts can be used to setup the Extension
Command to install the extension on the specific resource group VMs:
Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> | ForEach-Object {az vm extension set -n QualysAgent --publisher Qualys --version <Version> --vm-name $_.Name --resource-group $_.ResourceGroupName --settings '{"LicenseCode": "<Code>"}' --debug} 

Command to install the extension on all the VMs:
Get-AzVM | ForEach-Object {az vm extension set -n QualysAgent --publisher Qualys --version <Version> --vm-name $_.Name --resource-group $_.ResourceGroupName --settings '{"LicenseCode": "<Code>"}' --debug}

However, I need a script where I can select the names of the VMs individually.

You already have a script where you can select the VMs by name. Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -Name <VMName> | ...


PowerShell Script for installing Qualys Agent, However, I need a script where I can select the names of the VMs individually.

You can use the script below to install the extension on selected VMs in the resource group.

Note:  As I don’t have a QualysAgent license to install, I used the AAD extension for testing. In your case, replace the agent details with QualysAgent in the same script.

$RGNames = "VM-RG"
$Version = "1.3.0.0" 
$publisher = "Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory"
$name = "AADLoginForWindows"

$vms = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $RGNames

Write-Host "Available VMs in resource group '$RGNames':"
$vms.Name | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ }


$selectedvms = Read-Host "Enter the names of the VMs you want to install the Qualys Agent on (comma-separated)"

$selectedvmsArray = $selectedvms.Split(",").Trim()

foreach ($vm in $vmList) {
    if ($selectedvmsArray -contains $vm.Name) {
        Write-Host "Installing Qualys Agent on VM: $($vm.Name)"
        az vm extension set -n $name --publisher $publisher --version $Version --vm-name $vm.Name --resource-group $vm.ResourceGroupName --debug
    }
}

The code will display all VMs in the resource group and ask you to select the VMs where you want to install the extension.
Output:


Agent not installed on VM named: Venkat-VM2

